# Как через api или другим автоматизированным способом добавить telegram бота в каналы по ссылкам

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот, который собирает ссылки на каналы. Далее необходимо из этих каналов собирать сообщения.

Вопрос: как это сделать?

Необходимо этого бота как-то подключить в эти каналы? Либо это делается не ботом? Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Советы подобные "прочесть документацию для начала" - можно не озвучивать как я понимаю?(ответы на оба вопроса там отвечены, и есть \нету в бот апи и как быть)